# Restore purchase not working after updating mac app, SwiftyStoreKit

Tags: swift, macos, in-app-purchase, macos-catalina

I am using SwiftyStoreKit for In-App Purchases. It was working fine. Until I uploaded a new build, few users reporting that their Restore Purchase not working.
I have tested both In-App and Restore purchase in debug mode, its working fine on my side.
Does anyone know what could be the problem?

I'm using macOS 10.15.2 Catalina

Comment: Some of my users have the same issue. It seems it is related to the latest update of macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

After trying different ways, I finally resolved my issue.
In **AppDelegate** Class method **applicationDidFinishLaunching**, I wrote these 2 lines at start:

```
    let receiptRefreshRequest = SKReceiptRefreshRequest()
    receiptRefreshRequest.start()
```

After starting this receipt refresh request, restore purchase successfully started working.